# Not getting updated state value in function call even after setState is done

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Below is my useEffect call to get the initial chat for my chat window.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        SessionId: 12,
      },
    };
    axios
      .get(
        "http://localhost:8084/online/visitors/bot_123/",
        config
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("Data",res.data.content[0].title);
        setLastConversation(res.data.content);
   
        res.data.content.map((content) => {
          setConversation((oldConv) => [
            ...oldConv,
            <div style={botChatStyle} key={content.title}>
              {content.title}
            </div>,
          ]);
          addIntentToConversation(content.buttonReplyLists);

        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("err in getting intents", err);
      });
  }, []);
```

here is my code for adding some button type lable if require from bot side

```
  const addIntentToConversation = (intentList) => {
    const newDiv = (
      <div style={intentStyle}>
        {intentList.map((intent) => {
          return ( 
            <button
              key={intent.btnTitle}
              style={intentBtnStyle}
              onClick={() => handleIntentClick(intent.btnTitle)}
            >
              {intent.btnTitle}
            </button>
           
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );

    setConversation((oldConv) => [...oldConv, newDiv]);
  };
```

Here is the code if user click on any button chip

```
const handleIntentClick = (text) => {
    setConversation((oldConv) => [
      ...oldConv,
      <div style={userChatStyle}>{text} </div>,
    ]);
    console.log("C",conversation);

    console.log("LC",lastConversation);

    const intentName = "Ticket Status"
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8084/online/visitors/intents?intentName=${intentName}`)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
  };
```

SO the problem is when I'm trying to get the value of **lastConversation** in **handleIntentClick**I'm not getting the updated value.

Comment: The updated value won't be available until the next render cycle. But repeatedly setting the state inside a `map()` call isn't great (and a misuse of `map()`). It looks like you should simply set the state to the data array and then handle the generation of JSX in the return block of the Component. But if you must generate the HTML in the useEffect do it without setting state, simply creating a new array, and then call `setConversation` once at the end.